# Rails SQL taking too long

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app using the following to select some records:

```
def mygroupsopenwos(employee)
  workorders.select("workorders.*").joins("left outer join empgroups ON empgroups.workgroup_id=workorders.workgroup_id").where("empgroups.employee_id = ?", employee).where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [230, 231, 232, 235] )
end
```

The app has about 25k workorders in it.

My understanding is that you want to keep responses within 500ms.  This one takes 5,000ms on Heroku.

How can I optimize the SQL?

Thanks for the help!!

PS - if it would help I could add the gem "squeel"

Comment: The query looks good. You can set appropriate indexes.

Comment: Thanks - would these make sense?  `add_index :empgroups, :employee_id
add_index :workorders, :wostatus_id
add_index :workorders, :workgroup_id`

Comment: You can add indexes and test performance.